# Fatal error dopo installazione

Tags: magento-1.8

Ciao a tutti,

dopo l'installazione di magento, il mio sito mi restituisce l'errore sotto:

```
Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /var/www/vhosts/nomedominio.it/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 215
```

E' capitato a qualcuno? 
Di cosa puo' trattarsi?

Grazie 1000 :)

English translation (somewhat):
Hello all,

After installation of magento, my website gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in /var/www/vhosts/nomedominio.it/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php on line 215
```

Has anyone seen this before? What causes this?

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

You specified an invalid connection type or did not install the [pdo_mysql extension](http://it.php.net/pdo_mysql) for php. This is the value in your `app/etc/local.xml` file:

```
<type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
```

Magento doesn't really support anything else, so you cannot set a different value, but check if there's a typo in there, if you have the extension installed.